# returns a new ArrayList of MenuItems containing just those menu items that are currently available

Tags: java

This is what i have so far

i am confused on how to compare using a method i have also tried
1. items.get(i).available() == true
and also using .equals

```
  public boolean available() { return myAvailability; }
```

//method

```
  ArrayList<MenuItem> availableItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>(items.size());
      int i = 0;
    while (i < availableItems.size())
    {
         boolean c = items.get(i).available();
        if (c == true)
        {
            availableItems.add(items.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        i++;

    }
    return  availableItems ;
```

//main

```
ArrayList<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        items.add( new MenuItem( "Big Bad Burger", 9.95, 2.15, 1, false ) );
        items.add( new MenuItem( "Cheeky Chicken", 5.95, 0.75, 1, true ) );
        items.add( new MenuItem( "Wild Wings", 5.95, 0.50, 0, false ) );
        items.add( new MenuItem( "Flying Fish", 15.95, 7.61, 1, false ) );
        items.add( new MenuItem( "Igloo Icecream", 1.95, 0.28, 2, true ) );

        ArrayList<MenuItem> available = availableItems( items );
        System.out.println(available);

        // should list:
        // Cheeky Chicken ($5.95) and Igloo Icecream ($1.95)
        for ( MenuItem item : available )
          System.out.println( item.menuString() );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
while (i < availableItems.size())
```

since `availableItems.size()` is 0.

The solutions are:

1. Use foreach loop, as in another answer
2. Use `removeIf`:

   ```
   ArrayList<MenuItem> availableItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>(items);
   availableItems.removeif(item -> !item.available());
   return availableItems;
   ```

Comment: Good catch, and nice use of `removeif`!

Comment: Can I please ask someone to format the answer? I can't figure out a way to have both list and code. When I have a list, code doesn't show properly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, Thanks for formatting! It's strange, I believe I tried what you did. Maybe I forgot some empty lines.

Comment: No problem. When you are below a list, everything is shifted of 4 spaces. Hence, since code formats as such with 4 spaces, when it's below a list item it should be moved of 8 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<MenuItem> getAvailableItems(List<MenuItem> items) {
    List<MenuItem> availableItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    for(MenuItem item : items)
        if(item.available())
            availableItems.add(item);

    return availableItems;
}
```

---

```
public static List<MenuItem> getAvailableItems(List<MenuItem> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .filter(MenuItem::available)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Though much cleaner than the original one, why this should yield a different result than the method written by OP?

Comment: Works but can you explain why            availableItems.add(items.get(i));
doesnt work?